# Python While Loop with 'AND' Operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, while-loop

I don't understand why the code below is returning wrong values.

Ideally, it should return the next Tuesday 4th from today. Instead, it returns today's date, `'2021-08-17'`:

```
import datetime

def tue_the_fourth():
    this_d = datetime.date.today()
    if this_d.weekday() ==1 and this_d.day ==4:
        return this_d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    else:
        while (this_d.weekday() is not 1) and (this_d.day is not 4):
            this_d=this_d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            print(this_d)
    return this_d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: So, what do you get instead? An exception, a wrong value (share that value!), your computer starts singing Opera badly? Please share those details, they could help us help you!

Comment: Be aware that using `X is not 1` is a bad practice. It only works for a small range of integers (-5 to 255 IIRC) thanks to an optimization done by CPython. It will not work in general.

Comment: Style note: `is not 1` and `is not 4` is not the correct way to test for integer values, use `!=`. That this works at all is a coincidence of how the main Python implementation caches small integer objects. Python 3.10 and up will warn you about those lines.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would say it's more than a mere style issue, it's just wrong, although as you state, on CPython it will work by accident.

Comment: Besides that, it seems you really want to use OR and not AND.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I prefixed it with 'style note' to avoid anyone thinking that that was the core of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal correctly, here's what I would write:

```
def tue_the_fourth():
    d = datetime.date.today()
    while (d.weekday() != 1) or (d.day != 4):
        d = d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    print(d)
    return d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

What's changed and why?

1. using `is not` for the logical `!=` is bad practice and inaccurate.
2. I changed the `while` to do a logical `or` on the conditions instead of `and`, basically this is how to get the required answer. Using answer will stop whenever we get a day that is either a Tuesday or a 4th, not both.
3. Overall cleanliness. No need for the `if - else` statement, if today is a Tuesday the 4th, then the while doesn't run a single time and today is returned.

Answer (score 2):

I'll ignore the incorrect use of `is not` for now, lets focus on the core issue: *your `while` test is **almost always false***. Sure, it is false for your target condition:

```
>>> (1 is not 1) and (4 is not 4)
False
```

Think about it:

- `1 is not 1` is False, because 1 is equal to 1, so it's the opposite of your test.
- `4 is not 4` is False, because 4 is equal to 4, so it's also the opposite of your test.

But, if you changed *one* of those values in the test you would **still** get `False`:

- `1 is not 1` is False,
- `17 is not 4` is True,

but your `while` loop only runs if **both** tests are true, because you used `and`. Since today is a Tuesday, but the date is the 17th of the month, the `while` loop will not run. On other days, it'll run until the first tuesday after the current date, or when it reaches the 4th of a month, whatever comes first.

You want to run the loop is *one or the other* is true, instead, so you want to use `or` here, but see below for a better option.

Note that the [correct test for integer inequality, is `!=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is), so you wanted to use:

```
while this_d.weekday() != 1 or this_d.day != 4:
```

but it might be easier to say:

```
while not (this_d.weekday() == 1 and this_d.day == 4):
```

You probably started with `this_d.weekday() == 1 and this_d.day == 4` and tried to invert that test, but you can't just add `not` to those tests and have it pass. You fell in to the classic boolean inversion trap and want to learn about [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> - `not (A or B) = (not A) and (not B)`
> - `not (A and B) = (not A) or (not B)`

The inverse of `A and B` is `(not A) or (not B)`. But, sometimes it is just clearer to keep the `not (A and B)` test as is.

Further notes:

- You don't need the first `if` test. The loop will not run when the condition is met too, so the whole `if` branch is redundant.
- You can use `this_d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)` instead of `this_d = this_d + datetime.timedelta(days=1)`. Look up *augmented assignment*, it is easier and shorter here.
- I'd return the `date` object. That would make your function re-usable in more situations. Sometimes you don't need to format a date object immediately!

So, I'd write it as:

```
def tue_the_fourth():
    this_d = datetime.date.today()
    while not (this_d.weekday() == 1 and this_d.day == 4):
        this_d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return this_d
```

and only format the date when you have to convert it to a string, as late as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

- Don't compare primitive values with `is` or `is not`, but with `==` or `!=`.
- The `while` condition (which is wrong) is not the negation of the `if` condition (which is correct)

I would also change the algorithm so that it doesn't step with one day at a time, since it is clear when the 4th isn't a Tuesday, none of the next days of the same month will be a match. You might as well add a month to the date and only then try again.

Also, you could make a generic function that finds a certain day of the month that is a certain weekday.

Here is an implementation of that idea:

```
import datetime

def next_month(dt, day, month_count=1):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime(dt.year + int(dt.month + month_count > 12),
                                 (dt.month + month_count - 1) % 12 + 1, day)
    except ValueError:  # invalid day in this month (like 30 February)
        return next_month(dt, day, month_count+1)

def find_next(day, weekday):
    this_d = datetime.date.today()
    this_d = next_month(this_d, day, int(this_d.day > day))
    while this_d.weekday() != weekday:
        this_d = next_month(this_d, day)
    return this_d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# find next 4th on a Tuesday
print(find_next(4, 1))  # 2022-01-04 (when run on 2021-08-17)
```